# Nifi handlehttprequest Failed to receive content from HTTP Request from due to Early EOF: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Early EOF

Tags: apache-nifi

We have a three node Nifi Cluster which is in backend and haproxy (LB) in frontend with a defined port for client to send request to the LB which will hit Nifi cluster in backend in round robin method.

We have a built a pipeline which has "HandleHTTPRequest" --> intermediate processing using multiple processors | "HandleHTTPResponse". Client application may send multi part payload with different file extension and within the pipeline we parse and process according to business logic and move it to Network/Central Drive.

When client application submits parallel payloads, we are being hit by below error on "HandleHTTPRequest" processor.

-I have tried to increase concurrent tasks for "HandleHTTPRequest" from "1 to 10" and all nodes on our cluster can handle the increase in tasks as we have enough CPU. 
-We have increased the container queue size from "50 to 80"
-Tried changing the timeout to 2 min in the controller service.

Error messaage in Nifi log:

```
Failed to receive content from HTTP Request from due to org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Early EOF: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Early EOF
org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Early EOF
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput$3.getError(HttpInput.java:1138)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput$3.noContent(HttpInput.java:1126)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.read(HttpInput.java:313)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
        at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ReadLineInputStream.read(ReadLineInputStream.java:131)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser.parse(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:769)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser.getParts(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:493)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.MultiParts$MultiPartsUtilParser.<init>(MultiParts.java:121)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.newMultiParts(Request.java:2410)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2333)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2319)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.HandleHttpRequest.onTrigger(HandleHttpRequest.java:575)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1165)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:203)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Looks like Jetty server is crashing in each of the node after few minutes and client application will start receiving 503 errors.

Any help in pointing out any changes to configuration will be of help.
Tx,
Vish

Comment: Seems your client not sending content `HttpInput$3.noContent`

Comment: Thanks @daggett for the insight. Client application may send zero byte head requests in between the actual requests where they send the actual payload of multipart files. But that should not allow the client application to get 503 errors correct? Also, we see each of the nifi node not accepting any request once we start seeing the error. Any help in debugging will be of great help

Comment: please edit question and provide the parameters of HandleHTTPRequest processor. also the request headers of the client to reproduce this error.